# Dereferencing Pointer Errors

Tags: c

Below are Lib.c and Lib.h files that are supposed to be part of a "movie theater" code, but I can't get some pointers to work together.

I've tried what I believe to be every combination but can't figure out why the pointers don't want to cooperate.

`StackLib.h`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#ifndef _STACKLIB_H
#define _STACKLIB_H

struct Node {
  char SeatRow;
  int SeatNumber;
  struct node *next_ptr;
}*StackTop;

void PushSoldSeat(struct Node **StackTop, char RowToAdd, int SeatToAdd);
void PopTickets(struct Node *StackTop);

#endif
```

.

```
#include "StackLib.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void PushSoldSeat(struct Node **StackTop, char RowToAdd, int SeatToAdd) {
  struct Node *NewNode = malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
  NewNode->SeatRow = RowToAdd;
  NewNode->SeatNumber = SeatToAdd;

  if (*StackTop == NULL) {
    *StackTop = NewNode;
    NewNode->next_ptr = NULL;
  } else {
    NewNode->next_ptr = *StackTop; //line 20
    *StackTop = NewNode;
  }
}

void PopTickets(struct Node *StackTop) {
  struct Node *TempPtr;
  if (StackTop == NULL) {
    printf("Pop not executed - stack is empty\n\n");
    return;
  }
  while (StackTop != NULL) {
    StackTop = TempPtr;
    printf("\n______________\n");
    printf("\n|             |\n");
    printf("\n|   Seat %c%d   |\n", StackTop->SeatRow, StackTop->SeatNumber);
    printf("\n|             |\n");
    printf("\n______________\n");
    TempPtr = StackTop->next_ptr; //line 41
    free(StackTop);
  }
  return;
}
```

When I gcc, the terminal prints out:

```
StackLib.c: In function ‘PushSoldSeat’:
StackLib.c:20: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
StackLib.c: In function ‘PopTickets’:
StackLib.c:41: error: incompatible types in assignment
```

Comment: Thank you for the edit. Extremely new to SO.

Comment: `struct node *next_ptr;` -->. `struct Node *next_ptr;`  (Look carefully).

Comment: Well, that changed the line 20 error from dereferencing to the same as line 41. So now I have two "incomaptible types in assignment."

Comment: In the PopTickets function, and forgive me if I'm wrong, but I don't think you should assign StackTop to a NULL TempPtr and then attempt to print the member variables of StackTop.

Comment: @BenedictAaronTjandra True `struct Node *TempPtr;
...
    StackTop = TempPtr;` is a run-time error as `TempPtr` in not initialized.

Comment: How would I go about fixing that?

Comment: Outside the while loop, set TempPtr to StackTop. Then inside the while function, set the printf function to print the member variables of TempPtr and set the while condition to (TempPtr != NULL). After that, do TempPtr = TempPtr -> next_ptr. I'd do the free-ing in a separate while loop as you still have StackTop.

Comment: `struct Node {
  ...
}*StackTop;` creates an object in the .h file called `StackTop` (a no-no).  Instead declare the `struct` as `struct Node {
  char SeatRow;
  int SeatNumber;
  struct Node *next_ptr;
};` in the .h file and in the .c file define `struct Node *StackTop;`  What  compiler are you using?  Is it a C or C++ compiler?

Comment: That's it! Ir compiles now. Thank you so much.

Comment: @chux hm can you tell me why you shouldn't declare structs in header files?

Comment: @BenedictAaronTjandra Declaring `struct` in a header is fine and good.  OP's code `struct Node { ... }*StackTop;` defines an object  `StackTop`.  This is the not good .h practice.

Comment: Ah sorry my bad. My question is why shouldn't you declare objects in header files? (i.e. just like what OP did)

Comment: @BenedictAaronTjandra I am **not** saying shouldn't  declare objects in header.  I am saying code should not define objects/variables in a header like `StackTop` as OP's code did.

Comment: @chux So this is a matter of practice? Or does OP's code compile because of your suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

There are few issues with the code, firstly bug is here

```
struct node *next_ptr;
```

as pointed by @chux It should be `struct Node *next_ptr;.`

secondaly, in `PopTickets()` while printing `struct Node` information, this

```
while (StackTop != NULL) { /* some code */ }
```

should be

```
struct Node *TempPtr = StackTop;
while (TempPtr != NULL) { /* some code */ }
```

as earlier code creates segmentation fault fault. Lets assume there is only one node then this

```
TempPtr = StackTop->next_ptr;
```

makes `TempPtr` as `NULL` but `StackTop` remains the same and again loop iterates(it shouldn't) and this `StackTop = TempPtr;` makes `StackTop` as `NULL` and when it access `StackTop->SeatRow` i.e `NULL->SeatRow` it get crashed.

Here is the sample code :

**trevor.c**

```
#include "StackLib.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
void PushSoldSeat(struct Node **StackTop, char RowToAdd, int SeatToAdd) {
        struct Node *NewNode = malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
        NewNode->SeatRow = RowToAdd;
        NewNode->SeatNumber = SeatToAdd;

        if (*StackTop == NULL) {
                *StackTop = NewNode;
                NewNode->next_ptr = NULL;
        }
        else {
                NewNode->next_ptr = *StackTop; //line 20
                *StackTop = NewNode;
        }
}

void PopTickets(struct Node *StackTop) {
        struct Node *TempPtr = StackTop;
        if(StackTop == NULL) {
                printf("Pop not executed - stack is empty\n\n");
                return;
        }
        while (TempPtr != NULL) {
                StackTop = TempPtr;
                printf("\n______________\n");
                printf("\n|             |\n");
                printf("\n|   Seat %c%d   |\n", StackTop->SeatRow, StackTop->SeatNumber);
                printf("\n|             |\n");
                printf("\n______________\n");
                TempPtr = StackTop->next_ptr; //line 41
                free(StackTop);
        }
}
int main(void) {
        struct Node *head = NULL;
        PushSoldSeat(&head,'a',5);
        PushSoldSeat(&head,'b',10);
        PushSoldSeat(&head,'c',15);
        PushSoldSeat(&head,'d',20);
        PopTickets(head);
        return 0;
}
```

**StackLib.h**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#ifndef _STACKLIB_H
#define _STACKLIB_H

struct Node {
  char SeatRow;
  int SeatNumber;
  struct Node *next_ptr; /* avoid spell mistake */
}StackTop; /* *stackTop is not required */

void PushSoldSeat(struct Node **StackTop, char RowToAdd, int SeatToAdd);
void PopTickets(struct Node *StackTop);

#endif
```

Now compile your code as below

```
gcc -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Werror trevor.c
```

Answer (score 0):

Capitalization is important to C. You have a `struct Node`, which you define. Inside, it has a pointer to a different type, `struct node`, which the compiler knows nothing about. You should use consistent capitalization and it should work better

By the way, I would expect `gcc` to print a warning in the .h file where you reference the new `struct node` for the first time. Be sure to compile with `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic` so it can help you catch a lot of errors.

Comment: How exactly would I compile with those? gcc ______.c -Wall?

Comment: @TrevorRowe Correct

Comment: Alright, so I tried that but I got this extremely weird output. "In function `_start':
(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `_start'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../lib64/crt1.o:(.text+0x0): first defined here" with that being repeated but with '_fini' and a few others

Comment: I'm not certain it would give a warning there and am having trouble testing, but it does give other useful warnings so I still recommend it. Yes, you just add those as command line flags, like that.

Comment: When you compile something which is not itself executable, like a library, you need the `-c` option as well. That tells it that this isn't a full program and not to generate the functions like `_start` which are used to set up and tear down the program.

Comment: Capitalizing the Node changed the line 20 error to match the line 41 error so now it's two "incompatible types in assignment"